# Using PHP in a header to redirect a webpage

Tags: php

I am using php to redirect a php file:

```
 header("location:viewprofile.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>");
```

The problem is the php is not taken as php and is taken literally, how can I echo the variable in this header?

Answer (score 4):

```
header("location:viewprofile.php?id=$id");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
header("Location: viewprofile.php?id={$id}");
```

1) notice the capital "L" in Location, although http headers should be case-insensitive (as by the specifications), some browsers treat them as case-sensitive (IE).

2) you should not use relative paths if possible, because if a trailing slash is left by the browser in the url, you might be redirected to the wrong page (i.e. http://domain.com/folder/ will redirect to http://domain.com/folder/viewprofile.php?id=5)

Answer (score 0):

No need to echo it. just use the following code:

```
header("location:viewprofile.php?id=".$id);
```

the stored value in the variable $id will be attached to the header string.

Comment: You don't need to concatenate with double quotes. Interpolation will work fine.